# Yes or no question with python on discord

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a Discord bot which can ask a yes-or-no question and respond to the user's answer. I tried this code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'ask me a question':
        await message.channel.send('Yes or No')
        if message.content == 'yes':
            await message.channel.send('correct!')
        elif message.content == 'no':
            await message.channel.send('wrong')
```

The bot responds to 'ask me a question', but when I type in 'yes' or 'no' I don't get a response. Why doesn't it work, and how can I fix it?

Comment: For the close voters: just because the naive approach has an obvious flaw doesn't make it a typo. The correct way to write the code isn't obvious, and I don't see a direct way to get the necessary information from the documentation either. I'm usually the one scolding people for a lack of research or debugging, but I really think the core of the question is fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I [edit]ed the question to ask a question directly and avoid [irrelevant conversation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721), as this is **not a discussion forum**. Please carefully study the changes so that you can ask better questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you don't ask it to wait for another message. Which means your variable `message` is still the "ask me a question" message. Intead, you should use `bot.wait_for("message")`, that will return the next message sent.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'ask me a question':
        await message.channel.send('Yes or No')

        response = await bot.wait_for("message")
        if response.content == 'yes':
            await message.channel.send('correct!')
        elif response.content == 'no':
            await message.channel.send('wrong')
```